# KeyCloak create composite role

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to create composite role by API

```
POST /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles
body:
{"name":"|studio-5|-|project-5|-|agreement-39|-|team-member-agreement-admin|", "clientRole": true, "composite": true, "composites": {"name": ["owner"]}}
```

What should I send in composites? I tried array of role names but it just create role with composite false

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

(realm roles only) To make a `Role A` composite of a `Role B` do the following:

```
POST <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/roles-by-id/<ROLE_ID_OF_ROLE_B>/composites
```

with the request:

```
[{"id":"<ID_OF_ROLE_A>","name":"RoleCompositve","composite":false,"clientRole":false,"containerId":"test"}]
```

The IDs from the roles you can get it via Admin Console:

- Go to the Realm that contains the role:
- Select Roles;
- Click on the Particular Role;
- In the Url the last part is the ID of the Role.

Or via Keycloak Admin Rest Api:

```
Get <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<REALM_NAME>/roles/<ROLE_NAME>
```